# github actions: using variables in global env section

Tags: github-actions

Is it possible to use variables inside global `env` sections in github workflows?
Something like following code snippet

```
env:
  isqa: ""
  local_tag: "${{env.isqa}}latest"
  project: "important"
  aws_taskdef: "project-${project}-something"
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You cannot put these `env` references on the same level, but you can specify the to-be-referenced values on the workflow or job level, and reference them in the step level. It would be something like this

```
jobs:
  test:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    env:
      IS_QA: "qa"
      PROJECT: "important"
    steps:
      - run:
          echo ${{env.IS_QA}}
          echo ${{env.LOCAL_TAG}}
          echo ${{env.PROJECT}}
          echo ${{env.AWS_TASKDEF}}
        env:
          LOCAL_TAG: "${{env.IS_QA}}-latest"
          AWS_TASKDEF: "project-${{env.PROJECT}}-something"
```

You can see my testing in here, https://github.com/chenrui333/github-action-test/blob/main/.github/workflows/env-test.yaml

Comment: ```runs-on:``` doesn't support ```env``` so for example ```runs-on: ${{env.OS_VERSION}}``` will not work

Comment: Based on this doc page `runs-on:` does support `env`: https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/environment-variables

Comment: At least on my tests, it only works with env at the step level and not the job level.